# Prompt Multiplo WorkWithPlus exemplo em Trasações

Tags: genexus

Bom dia,

Estou tentando usar o promptmultiple do work with plus para preencher o grid do level de uma transação.
Mas ao selecionar os dados ele não atualiza o grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia,

O PromptMultiple de WorkWithPlus é para usar como filtros de pesquisa (usando o filtro FilterMultiple com type: prompt), nos objetos Selection, Prompt, etc mas não é para usar na transação para inserção de dados.

Tem um exemplo de uso no seguinte link: http://www.workwithplus.com/eng/help/index.htm?Page=SelectionFilter.htm na seção: Prompt Filter Multiple.

Qualquer outra dúvida pode nos escrever a nossa conta de suporte: support@workwithplus.com

Att,
Eugenia